# Python: Pickle output for each iteration using multiprocessing

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize some of my existing code. I would like to save the output of each iteration as soon as it completes so that I do not have to store the entire loop in memory. Basically something like this:

```
import cPickle as pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    outf = open('test_mp.pkl', 'wb')

    def f(x):
        pickle.dump([x, x*x], outf, -1)
        return x*x

    pool = Pool(4)
    out = pool.map(f, range(100))
    print out
```

The code runs without errors or warnings and produces the correct value for 'out'. However, when I try to read in the pickle file that was produced, nothing seems to have been written to it at all:

```
>>> f = open('test_mp.pkl', 'rb')
>>> pickle.load(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4d7131bbd231> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.load(f)

EOFError:
```

I'm currently at a loss for why I can't dump to a pickle object in the middle of a loop. I have tried this code without multiprocessing (i.e. just a for loop) and it works just fine.

I've also moved the function outside of main() and passed in 'outf' as an additional argument. That method gives an error about trying to write to a closed file.

How can I save my output in a pickle file when my loop is parallelized?

Comment: different processes *don't share state*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a problem with the threads trying to access the same filehandle at the same time. Instead, you can pickle into a list using the `.dumps` method and then dump the combined bytearray into a file at the end. Otherwise, you can pickle from each process into a separate file handle, so you will have one file for each process.

Also, pickling is not the ideal way to store huge amounts of data. There are specially designed file formats such as HDF5 (http://www.h5py.org/) that are really well suited for huge numerical data storage. The h5py implementation is very mature and easy to use, and can also allow you to store your data in parallel.